# Group Recyclerview Items that getting from a Json

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I am getting a Json output from the server.

This is my Json look like

```
{
  "feed": [
    {
      "order_no": "70000004",
      "quotation_no": "abc004a"
    },
    {
      "order_no": "70000003",
      "quotation_no": "abc003a"
    },
    {
      "order_no": "70000001",
      "quotation_no": "abc001a"
    },
    {
      "order_no": "70000001",
      "quotation_no": "abc001b"
    }
  ]
}
```

I know how to populate this in a recyclerview. But what I want is grouping this json using **order_no** and populate. For example there are two **70000001**. So i only need to show one **70000001** order no.

This is my custom row .xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#dbdbda"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/parent_list_item"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Parent Title"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryColorText"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/parent_q_item_one"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:text="Q Title"
                android:textColor="@color/secondaryColorText"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/parent_q_item_two"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:text="Q Title"
                android:textColor="@color/secondaryColorText"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

After grouping, I need to show only one **order_no** in **parent_list_item** **(70000001)** and under that I need to show one **quotation_no** in the first text view and second **quotation_no** in the second text view under same **order_no**

My adapter class

```
public class OrderQuatationHistory extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderQuatationHistory.ItemViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<OrderHistoryData> orderHistoryDataArrayList;

    public OrderQuatationHistory() {
    }

    public OrderQuatationHistory(Context context) {
        orderHistoryDataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setOrderHistoryList(ArrayList<OrderHistoryData> orderHistoryDataArrayList) {
        this.orderHistoryDataArrayList = orderHistoryDataArrayList;
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, orderHistoryDataArrayList.size());
    }

    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_order_history_p_row, parent, false);
        ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(view);
        return itemViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        OrderHistoryData orderHistoryData = orderHistoryDataArrayList.get(position);
            holder.orderNo.setText(orderHistoryData.getOrderNo());
            holder.quotationNo.setText(orderHistoryData.getQuotationNo());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return orderHistoryDataArrayList.size();
    }

    public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView orderNo,quotationNo;

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            orderNo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_list_item);
            quotationNo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_q_list);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would maybe go with filtering the list before passing it to adapter/recycler view. Maybe some Map, or better with some For loop. Maybe not that good option, but in the future it would be much easier to update and handle (if you need multiple, group by something else, sort by name, sort by date)

Comment: You're creating it with ArrayList size of zero, so it calls getItemCount to know how many times it will run onBindViewHolder. Since size equal to zero it returns no view. BaseAdapter works this way so I think RecyclerView.Adapter is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... For avoiding of duplicate value,you can use this Method.

```
ArrayList<Integer> jSonOrder=new ArrayList();
```

int order_no= assigned values that you have retrieved from JSon.

```
   if (!jSonOrder.contains(order_no)) {
     jSonOrder.add(order_no);
   }
```